# Why is the onAfterRendering of sap.ui.core.Control.prototype undefined?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm writing a Web-based App with SAPUI5 and need to implement a possibility to capture a digital signature.

I have found this custom control on the web: [Digital signature as control in SAPUI5](https://fiori.acando-live.de/2018/09/digitale-unterschrift-als-control-in-sapui5/)

One of my colleagues has actually already used this exact control and it works for him, while it does not for me, it simply doesn't activate, hence I can't draw anything on it. The cavnas however does load and is detectable with the chrome detection tool.

I so far basically tried narrowing down the problem of why it doesn't work and have so far come to the conclusion that the lines

```
if (sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
  sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments); //run the super class's method first
}
```

should be the issue. For me, the inside of the if-condition returns undefined while for my colleague returns anonymous. Hence for him it runs the inside code while for me it doesn't.

In case more code is needed, I can provide regarding snippets.

```js
onAfterRendering: function (oEvent) {
    //if I need to do any post render actions, it will happen here
    console.log(sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onAfterRendering);
    if (sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
        sap.ui.core.Control.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments); //run the super class's method first
        this._drawSignatureArea(this);
        this._makeAreaDrawable(this);
        var that = this;//make the control resizable and redraw when something changed
        sap.ui.core.ResizeHandler.register(this, function () {
            that._drawSignatureArea(that);
        });
    }
},
```

I would expect it to hook the listeners for drawing on the board and make the image available. I get no error messages due to the code itself being (normally) fine otherwise.

Comment: Are you using the same UI5 version as your colleague? In either case it looks to me you can simply move all the code except the "apply" line to be after the `if`. There shouldn't be a reason for them to be inside it.

Comment: I in fact seem to be using another UI5 Version and will try an updated one. Moving the lines out of the if Block results in the canvas still not being drawable while also making me unable to click buttons. Haven't further investigated yet as to why this behaviour is occuring.

Comment: Update: It does execute the if-Block with the current UI5 Version, but the control still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: `onAfterRendering` on `sap.ui.core.Control` was added in 1.54: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Control.js which might explain the need for an `if` statement.

Comment: Ok thank you for that info, that just means this piece of code is not usable for me since I depend on 1.38, but I managed to resolve the issue by rewriting my code. I am no longer using a control element anymore though which probably makes my solution useless for others.